# SSIS script task failing to send email SMTPexception:System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed

Tags: c#, ssis, smtp, etl, script-task

I am using a script task in SSIS to send emails. Code snapshot below:

[image: Script task code]

It is failing with the below error:

[image: error snapshot]

Please note, it was working fine a couple of weeks back.
What I have tried so far:

1. Tried changing SMTP details to gmail. It works fine with gmail after allowing the "less secure apps" setting
2. Added "SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;" in code - it did not help
3. Tried sending email through powershell command. It works from there. Powershell command below:

```
Send-MailMessage -To “<emailId>” -From “<emailId>” -Subject “Your message subject” -Body “Some important plain text!” -Credential (Get-Credential) -SmtpServer “smtp.office365.com” -Port 587 -UseSsl
```

Not sure why the email is not working from the SSIS script task. Please help with any pointers for further investigation.

Comment: Most likely you are sending too many requests and get blocked by office365.com.

Comment: The email is failing to get a receipt from the destination.  The account may no longer be working or the destination mail box may be full.  I have one customer whose email server was not working properly and returning emails errors.

Comment: Have tried this with my own office email account as well which is active but I got same error. I am able to send and receive email with designated email account using outlook so it seems problem only when sending email through SSIS.

Comment: Just checked with admin. He checked notification logs and confirmed that there are no login failures for this email account.

Comment: Sharing version details in case anyone wants to try to reproduce the issue:
Visual studio 2017 (SSDT) version 15.9.14
Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.8.04084

Comment: And also on this combination: 
Visual studio 2017 (SSDT) version 15.9.36
Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.8.03761